# RecyclerView scrolling issue in android MotionLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, animation, android-motionlayout

We have been working on an android project, and we faced with a problem in animation into the **motionLayout** when **recyclerView** is scrolling (*you can see in video*).

after scroll in anywhere on screen animation is fine but after scroll recyclerview appBar animation is run but so weird.

I added picture and video from UI architect to avoid confusion.

[image]

**ProfileFragment.kt**

```
    private fun coordinateMotion() {
        val appBarLayout: AppBarLayout? = binding.appbarLayout
        val motionLayout: MotionLayout = binding.profileHeaderInfo as MotionLayout

        val p = DecimalFormat("0.0");

        val listener = AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener { unused, verticalOffset ->
            val seekPosition = -verticalOffset / appBarLayout?.totalScrollRange!!.toFloat()
            motionLayout.progress = seekPosition
            Log.d(TAG, "coordinateMotion: $seekPosition")
        }

        appBarLayout?.addOnOffsetChangedListener(listener)
    }
```

**ProfileFragment:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/profile_include"
                layout="@layout/profile_layout_content" />
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
                android:id="@+id/profile_header_info"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                app:motionDebug="SHOW_PATH"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="80dp"
                android:background="@color/primary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
                app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_profile_xml_profile_header_info_scene"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                .....

            </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image: app ui architect]

**fragment_profile_xml_profile_header_info_scene**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/profile_user_desc"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_user_name">
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_user_login"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_user_login"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_user_login" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_name"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/profile_image">
            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="10sp" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_login"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

            <CustomAttribute
                motion:attributeName="textSize"
                motion:customDimension="8sp" />
        </Constraint>
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_user_desc"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_image"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_user_login"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_user_name"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_user_name" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_header_divider"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profile_user_desc"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_image"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profile_user_desc" />
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/profile_header_company_icon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            motion:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profile_header_divider"
            motion:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="1000">
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_divider" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
        <KeyFrameSet>
<!--            <KeyAttribute-->
<!--                android:alpha="0"-->
<!--                motion:framePosition="100"-->
<!--                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_user_desc" />-->
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_company" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_location" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_create_at" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_company_icon" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0.0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_location_icon" />
            <KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="100"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_create_at_icon" />
        </KeyFrameSet>

        <OnSwipe />

    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

Comment: Any progress? I have same almost same issue

Answer (score 0):

You should determine two transition one startToEnd one endToStart
after that add keyAttribute for things that is alpha zero like this

```
<KeyAttribute
                android:alpha="0"
                motion:framePosition="20"
                motion:motionTarget="@+id/profile_header_company_icon" />
```

When you use framePosition="100" your company icon gone at the end of motionlayout animation and this part of bad transition take place.
You can play with frame position on both start and end transition.